Would a material that could absorb 99.5% of light be able to protect someone from Night Vision?
I've done a bit of research on various materials that can absorb light, like Vanta Black, some paints and so on. My question is, could this material protect someone from Night Vision Goggles seeing as they use light to see in the dark?

Main issue with materials like this is that the user would look like a dark silhouette against almost-dark background. The same reason why deep blue, dark green or grey is better camouflage than black for most night environments. Generally you want to look like a part of your surrounding, no matter how dark it is.

Some night vision devices work vith visible light; they operate like very sensitive photo cameras. Some work with visible light plus near infrared light. Some work with thermal infrared radiation.

@AlexP Ahh ok, so there's a spectrum for what they all look for then. Interesting  so there'd need to be more layers of shielding and protection from verious forms of enhanced vision.

Yes, there are multiple kinds of devices for different applications. But in any case, black is a good camouflage color if one happens to be hiding in a really really dark place. In most natural situations black would stand out. Even in a very rural area with no light polution, most people's eyes adapt and most of the time one can see well enough to be able to walk around; a pure black thing would still stand out. (Possible exceptions are at night under a completely cloud-covered sky, or in a forest on a moonless night.)

This is a great idea, but let's look at the limitations of the real thing (like Vanta Black). The test is 99.5% of the visible spectrum, not 99.5% of all light. Light be photons. Radio waves be photons. Gamma rays be photons. And as Nosajimiki pointed out, the IR spectrum be photons. But should that stop you? A worldbuilding substance similar in concept to Vanta Black that could actually absorb 99.5% of all photons would definitely protect someone from night vision. And radar. And lasers. It would be close to the perfect nighttime stealth material.

@JBH the IR spectrum would remain complicated.  Just because you absorb 99.5% of IR does not keep you from emitting it.  And if you could somehow stop yourself from emitting or reflecting any EM radiation, then you would overheat very quickly because you'd have no way for your body to dump waste heat.

@JBH true that shouldn't stop be if I'm determined to write it but I want my work to reflect reality in the sense that even though it's a Science Fantasy story I still want that Science Fiction aspect of it to be Hard Science Fiction rather than Soft Science Fiction. So if it can't be done IRL or we're not at least researching it IRL, I'm not including it in my novels.

@Nosajimiki I didn't get the impression the OP was looking to stop emissions, but to stop detection. Thus, the concept would be applied to a shield, room, or perhaps a suit of clothing. You're right, though, about the fundamental problem with heat - it's gotta go somewhere.

True, the heat does have to go somewhere. I figured that could be taken care of with a Thermal Regulation component to the suit, kinda like how astronauts have a cooling system throughout their suits. It's kinda funny because I do have a suit specifically made for delving into Volcanos that has a giant refrigeration unit equipped to it. I might be able to miniaturize it though if the technology exists to do that.

@Altarious It really depends on what kind of night vision. Most night vision goggles you can buy are visible-light or near-infrared, which will NOT pick up heat signatures (thermal vision requires far infrared). Often the goggles come equipped with a near-infrared flashlight, which you can't see but the camera can. The goggles are just picking up reflected light. Thermal cameras, in contrast, tend to be more expensive and have low resolution/poor details.

@Altarious if you could somehow add shielding to prevent all radiation, the object would eventually absorb enough energy to melt it. If it keeps cool by, say, convection, then your night vision goggles would enable you to see the heat emitted by the warm air immediately around the object, even if you cannot see the object itself. If you somehow manage to down-shift all the radiation to (say) long wavelength microwaves, then congratulations, you've built Maxwell's Daemon and violated thermodynamics.

@JBH, perfectly light-absorbing material would not protect you from lasers, it would make you cook from the laser faster.

@GoingDurden The same claim can be made about any spectra or expression of light. The OP only asked about the ability to block the light. What to do with the absorbed energy hasn't been addressed in the question. (Although pointing out a problem like yours would make a good Frame Challenge!)

No, you would still glow in the IR spectrum
When solid matter absorbs light, it becomes hotter, and anything that holds heat emits blackbody radiation.  There are many kinds of Night Vision Systems, but many of them, especially military grade systems, include a long wave IR sensor that is designed to detect blackbody radiation in a temperature range that includes human body heat. In this case, you are not looking at light reflecting off of things so much as the IR radiation put off by how hot it is.  So, if you are 98F and your environment is 72F, you will still glow brightly even if you are not reflecting any visible light.
How to hide your IR signature
There are 2 kinds of IR stealth: passive and active.
Passive IR stealth relies on space gapping something between you and the camera.  So, if you have some kind of a shield that is opaque in the IR spectrum and the same temperature as your environment and you hold it out in front of yourself, the thermal night vision goggles will detect the 72F surface of the shield and not your 98F body behind it.  This can be further improved with IR refractive paint. This paint is not meant to absorb IR light or prevent you from emitting it, it's designed to scatter or reflect it so that you look like a blur or a pattern similar to your environment in Night Vision instead of a geometrically shaped shield or what not which makes you even harder to see against your background.
That said, most of the time, you will not have a "shield".  What most soldiers use for passive thermal stealth is disruptive camouflage. By covering yourself in a netting material, you will still technically glow but it will break up your outline so much that you no longer look like a person and you can blend into your background.
However, many night vision systems include low-light cameras.  These are just highly sensitive traditional or near infrared cameras designed to boost visible light.  These don't work as well in true darkness as thermal cameras, but they can be harder to fool because they often produce clearer images.  For this, traditional camouflage works better.  Instead of just trying to put on a plain black suit, visual camouflage uses a pattern of colors that look like your local environment and break up your shape.
If you want the best of both worlds, you can wear a Ghillie suit.  This will break up your silhouette in both the visible light and IR spectrum. Some Ghillie suits like ATGS-17 also even include IR refracting technology.

Active IR stealth is used mostly on armored vehicles that can't effectively space gap themselves.  This is basically an A/C system built into the outer layer of armor.  Not only can this match the environment, but it can selectively heat and cool plates to create IR patterns to change what you look like; so, you can make a tank look like a car or a line of trees, etc.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Night visors amplify infrared and/or visible light. If your super black coating doesn't block all those frequencies, the coating would not work against it.
Additionally, if it worked egregiously, you would have another problem: the background against which your masked object stands will not be masked, so, quite paradoxically, it will stand out more. Think of wearing a black coat at night on a dark road or wearing the same dark coat on a snowy surface: where would you be more noticeable?
If you want to not be seen, you have to blend with the background.

You know I just read up on one of these materials that can actually block Infrared Light. But I'm assuming that still wouldn't get rid of the object standing out due to the background. Would active camouflage like bending light or something more realistic like the Chinese Camera Suit work for getting rid of that problem?

Black? That how we describe something that readile absorbs light, but in thermodynamics it also describes something that emits light when hot.
Black in the thermal infa-red would mean you glow in that spectrum.
So, no you'd be better off using the opposite, mirrors.
Mirrors show a reflection of the surroundings; what better way to blend in?
This is especially true at night when there are no shadows or accidental reflections of the Sun.

umm.... the 'black' in blackbody doesn't refer to the color of the thing that emits, rather it refers to the fact that even when something is black, it still emits. In other words, everything emits blackbody radiation, it's just that black objects only emit blackbody radiation without all that other reflected [presumably] visible light.

untrue. highly reflective things emit proportionltely less black body radiaton.  hence "furnace" in the definition.

Do you have a citation for this claim? The reality is that emissivity is independent of color.

Yer making stuff up! How does a vacuum flask work? why is it silvered?  Can you make a free energy heat pump using a black surface facing a mirror?

@user121330 Your intuition may say that emissivity is independent of colour, but experiment disagrees. See Wikipedia: Leslie cube. Do not confuse your beliefs with reality. (I completely understand, though: my own intuition still says that colour is irrelevant, to my chagrin, even though I've replicated that experiment.)
